# Selenium - pulling data from a website table assign to variable

Tags: vba, selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver

I am attempting to pull a value and a header (string) from a website, but unable to find the element using selenium.

My Code
I used Firebug to get the XPath and this is what it determined:

```
//*[@id="DimensionForm"]/p[1]/table/tbody/tr[3]/td[3]
```

Code

```
Dim Right as double
Dim Marker as string

Marker = selenium.findElementByXPath("//*[@id="DimensionForm"]/p[1]/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[3]").getAttribute("value")
Right = selenium.findElementByXPath("//*[@id="DimensionForm"]/p[1]/table/tbody/tr[3]/td[3]").getAttribute("value")
```

HTML CODE

```
<form  id="DimensionForm" name="validate" action="Dimension" method="post">
<div style="margin-top: 7px"></div>
<p><table width="100%" cellspacing="0" border="0" cellpadding="0" class="element">
<tr>
<td>&nbsp;</td><td class="formtitlenobg" colspan="6" align='right'>
AREA DIMENSIONS&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; (AREA&nbsp;A) <span class='quote'> &nbsp; Front</span> 25.24</td>
</tr>
<tr align="right">
<td class="tablerowlightgreen" width=10>&nbsp;</td>
<th class="formtitle"  width=250 align="left">Property</th>
<th class="formtitle" width=50>Check</th>         <th class="formtitle" width=75>Front</th>
<th class="formtitle" width=75>Center</th><th class="formtitle" width=75>Left</th>
<th class="formtitle" width=120>Right</th>
<th class="formtitle" width=100>Total</th>
<td class="tablerow" width=50>&nbsp;</td>
<td class="tablerow">&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
<tr align="right" nowrap>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td class="table" align="left"><strong>
Property&nbsp;O</strong></td>
<td class="table">+</td>
<td class="table">10</td>
<td class="table">12</td>
<td class="table"><strong>12</strong></td>
<td class="table"><strong><font class="front">
100</font></strong></td>
<td class="table">120</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
</table></td>
</tr></table>
```

Comment: What's happening when you try your code?  Nothing, or an exception?  If it is an exception, can you edit your question and add the exception?

Comment: Seems that in the end of your html you have extra `</td></tr></table>`, and you are missing `</p></form>`

Answer (score 1):

You have incorrectly nested quotes:

```
selenium.findElementByXPath("//*[@id="DimensionForm"]/p[1]/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[3]")
```

Perhaps you meant:

```
selenium.findElementByXPath("//*[@id='DimensionForm']/p[1]/table//tr[2]/td[3]")
```

Note the single-quotes in the second line!

Comment: I had tried that, it still did not work. Thanks for the note though.

Comment: Drop the "tbody", as some browser will not render that element.